# How do I get public key info (RSA Bit) using jsrsasign?

Tags: rsa, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, pem

I'm using this library jsrsasign. I'd like to know how get this information from `certificate.pem`

> Public Key info: RSA-2048 Bit

When I open my certificate in console, it shows me this info:

> Subject Public Key Info:
>   
> Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>   
> Public-Key: (2048 bit)

Which class/method from jsrsasign should I use to get this info?